# How to pass route param as bindable value to component's viewmodel (not view)

Tags: aurelia, bindable

I have used route navigation where I access route params from activate.

`app.ts`

```
export class App {
   configureRouter(config) {
    config.map([
        { route: 'student/:id', name: 'student', moduleId: 'student',  nav: true, title: 'student', href: '#' }
    ]);
}
```

}

`student.ts`

```
export class Student {
    id;

activate(params) {
    this.id = params.id;
   }
}
```

The page it routes to is built using several components that need this parameter to be passed.

```
<template>
    <require from="grade" > </require>
    <h1> Student - ${id} </h1>
    <grade id.bind="id"></grade>
    <department id.bind="id"></department>
<template>
```

In my grade view, it gets the id correctly when I display it in an html element (after I make it a bindable in viewmodel):

`grade.html`
       `<span>${id}</span>`

But, I cannot get the id in the viewmodel of grade i.e.
`grade.ts`

```
    export class Grade{
      @bindable id;
        constructor() {
          console.log("id=", this.id};
 }
```

comes up as undefined. I tried to access it via activate as I did in student but looks like templates are not activated when the page loads. I think the issue is not with the routing, but how to access bindable values in viewmodel in general. I tried one-time and two-way bindingmodes as well and they gave same results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it's undefined is because you're calling it in the `constructor`. The bindable variable is filled in the `attached` phase.

If you try calling it in an attached method like this:

```
attached() {
   console.log("id=" + this.id);
 }
```

It should be filled.

For more information on Aurelia Component Lifecycles, click [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/aurelia/aurelia_component_lifecycle.htm)

Comment: It should also be available in the bind() phase, which occurs before attached().